# Angular js plunkr not working while accessing through iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

i am not able to access Model for model in below plunkr, please find plunkr below.please help.

```
<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
  <h2>Teens - using external HTML file as template</h2>
  <iframe src="teen-external.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's the [**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/A7BbpkVlgc3ACXm1Iac7?p=preview) for any ref.

Comment: Look at the example you forked again. The template is meant to be included in the current page through the angular directive, not inside an iframe. You'd have to move all the angular code to the iframe as well if it would have been meant to render there.

Comment: Hi Shilly, thanks for Answering, i am new to angularjs can you please show an plunkr example of the same

Comment: Just go to the example you forked to create your plunker. It contains the right syntax to get the example working. You have to replace `<iframe src="teen-external.html"></iframe>` with `<teen-internal></teen-internal>`. How did you find this plunker? Since it seems to be part of some tutorial, that will learn you what you're asking here.

Comment: Hi Shilly, i was trying things with this plunkr, as want to use this in my project, really stuck..Please find the plunkr with directive.
https://plnkr.co/edit/g06CvME4FweWjjSOc5kw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems in your example, first the html source was loaded in iframe, which loads it as a simple html and renders it inside the iframe without angular parsing it to do all the mastache interpolation.

To correct this since you've already created a directive that renders the `teen-external.html` which would allow angular to parse the said html and interpolate the relevant fields. to do this simply use the directive inside your `index.html` file like.

```
<teen-internal> </teen-internal>
```

or

```
<div teen-internal></div>
```

Another problem is that you're trying to access a variable/model defined inside the parents `$scope` which is not possible without going via the `$scope.$parent`. Even if you do it using the `$parent` it is considered a really bad practice. To this a bit more elegantly angular provides a sort of model/variable passing from parent to the child, to do this you need to change both the `index.html` and the `teensInternal` directive code.

in your `index.html`
    
or

```
<div teens-internal teens="teens"></div>
```

This sets the `teens` property on the `teensInternal`'s `$scope` to the `teens` from the parent's(`PersonCtrl`) `$scope`. Now in your directive code you must define how the binding works for `teens` property, here you can define it as a read only `@` also called one way binding (modification done inside `teensInternal` is not reflected inside the parent controller) or as writable `=` two way binding (both `teensInternal` and `PersonCtrl` share the same object, so the modifications are reflected in both sides) to do this change

```
scope: {

},
```

to

```
scope: {
  teens: '=' // or "@" for one way binding
},
```

This tells the directive that whatever was passed to `<teens-internal teens="teens"></teens-internal>` through **`teens`**`="<model's name>"` can be used inside the directive's `$scope`.

Plunkr: [plunkr source](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ga2ueoh7H5oNw7932rIG?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @Minato, Thanks for answering, i get the point, and also while solving the issue myslef i got to the direction of using iframe for the same, due to some css issue in my html rendering, can you please find where i am getting wrong in rendering the same code in iframe wrong.
Please find Plunkr for further clarifiation.
https://plnkr.co/edit/uQfhnkdyBz1SOHKIOcE5?p=preview

Comment: @Anup You cannot use angular from inside the iframe۔

Comment: Hi @Minato, The plunkr without iframe is working fine, but when i am calling the same directive into a master page of asp.net, then it did not work, is it that we cannot use directive for showing data from master page.